# Python, Scipy: how to fix arguments of function being fit by optimize.curvefit()?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Let's say I have a function `f(x,a,b,c)` in Python that (just as an example) could look something like this:

```
def f(x,a,b,c):
  return a*x*x + b*x + c
```

(just as a general example; my function does not look like that)

The following

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

x = range(1,10)
y = range(2,11)

output = opt.curvefit(f,x,y)
```

would find the values of `a`,`b`, and `c` that best fit `f(x,a,b,c)` to `y`.

Let's say now that, with `f(x,a,b,c)` still defined the same way above, I want to fix one of the parameters (let's say `a`).  Is there any way I can still use opt.curvefit(f,x,y) with `f` still defined as above but with `a` fixed?

To be specific: I still want to be able to pass `a` to `f`, I just don't want it to be a parameter that gets varied when `curvefit()` tries to fit `f(x,a,b,c)` to `y`.

Comment: You could just make a wrapper (using lambda or functools.partial) that accepts one fewer argument and then calls `f` with the fixed argument as well as its own.

Comment: I still want to pass the fixed argument to `f`.

Comment: Yes, that is what your wrapper will do.

Comment: Could you show an example?  I am having a hard time picturing this.